# Redesigning android app to use tabbed navigation

Tags: android, tabs, navigation

I have an android app which is fully functional. Right now, I have a main activity that works as a menu/home screen from which you can go to different sections of the app. For the new version, I would like to redesign the navigation so that these options are always available in the form of a tab bar like this (keeping the action bar as it is):

[image]

I haven't worked with these before, but from what I have read, it doesn't seem complicated. The problem is that I already have a whole bunch of activities that are used to working the other way. I recall reading something about changing `Activity` classes to `TabActivity`. This is something I would strongly want to avoid, because I have a considerable depth of inheritance as I have grouped similar functionalities in different base abstract classes which in the end extend `Activity`.

What I would like to know is your advice on what would be the most efficient or simplest way to make this change, while breaking as little as possible features of the app. Is there a way I can simply switch the activity being shown as the selected tab changes? How would you re-structure the application?

Any help will be appreciated and I can give you more information if needed.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For the new version, I would like to redesign the navigation so that these options are always available in the form of a tab bar like this (keeping the action bar as it is):

Either use `FragmentTabHost` or a `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator (e.g., `PagerTabStrip`).

> What I would like to know is your advice on what would be the most efficient or simplest way to make this change

Either use `FragmentTabHost` or a `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator (e.g., `PagerTabStrip`). Personally, I'd use `ViewPager`, assuming the content did not itself involve horizontal swipe gestures.

> Is there a way I can simply switch the activity being shown as the selected tab changes?

Not in a way that will look very good.

> How would you re-structure the application?

If you want this sort of flexibility, to organize your content in different ways (e.g., tabs on phones, more of the content visible at once on tablets), convert your activities into fragments.